# angular 2 file change - changes all app

Tags: angular, gulp

when I change one file and save, it takes about one minute until it reload again.

I see many "file changed" in the console.

what can be the reason for that ?

I'm using "gulp".

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using something like `gulp serve` to host your web application on localhost?

It should not take one minute unless you have a *very* large application. It should take maybe 5-10 seconds.

I'm assuming it is using something like Browsersync, Live reload, or webpack to recompile your entire project. The term for this is "Hot module reloading".

You may also want to look into "Hot module replacement" where the entire project doesn't need to be recompiled. Instead, the changes are injected into your live project on-the-fly.